# How do I compile a Jar w/ a external lib

Tags: jar, compilation, jdeveloper

Well I'm new to to stackoverflow so I'm sorry if I misinterpreted some of this Q&A rules feel free to point out any mistake, and for my English, since I'm not an English native speaker.

Now, although I program for several years, I've been forced to use an old version of JDeveloper on this project I'm in, and I've had some beginner issues, because I'm used to let the IDE do all the hard work.

My objective is, to compile my project to a jar and execute it in the server.

So far, I got my app to run and work on my IDE which is JDev 9.0.3.2 (OLD) and Java version is 1.3.1_01, but when I try to compile to a jar file for some reason the lib doesn't come along.

My code (partially ofc):

```
Connection con = null;

public Depositos() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Beginning ORACLE DB connection");

        try {
            String connstr="jdbc:oracle:thin:"+"@<hostname>"+":"+"<port>"+":"+"<SID>";
            System.out.println("connstr ok");

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            System.out.println("Class.forName ok");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection (connstr, "cic", "managercic");

            System.out.println("Connection successful");              
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
              throw new Exception("DB connection error "+e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

And I suspect the problem is over here, more precisely in here:
    "Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); "

My procedure is:
On the Depositos.java folder

I run this:

```
javac -verbose Depositos.java -classpath C:\oracle\ora92\jdbc\lib\classes12.jar
```

the output says it's all OK.

```
jar cfmv0 Depositos.jar MANIFEST.MF Depositos.class C:\oracle\ora92\jdbc\lib\classes12.jar
```

my MANIFEST.MF contains:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Oracle JDeveloper 10.1.3.4.0
Main-Class: Depositos.Depositos
```

When I run the code from the src folder with:

```
java oic.OIC
```

my output is:

```
Beginning ORACLE DB connection
connstr ok
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: DB connection error oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
at Depositos.Depositos.<init>(Depositos.java:47)
at Depositos.Depositos.main(Depositos.java:98)
```

Which leads me to the conclusion that the error is in the line I stated above.

And I don't understand what I did wrong, I've read so many post from other forums, I don't know what's the right move anymore.

I tried several combinations of compiling commands.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should be more concerned about formatting your question properly than language issues. Your English is much better than some of the natives.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the oracle jar to your jar, and put a 'Class-path' attribute in the manifest.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Oracle JDeveloper 10.1.3.4.0
Main-Class: Depositos.Depositos
Class-path: <path to jar inside your jar>
```

From memory though, if your jar is signed, you need to sign the jars within it also.